# How to add Windows 7 loader to GRUB?

Tags: grub2, windows-7

I've successfully installed Ubuntu 11.10 alongside Windows 7. During installation I've manually changed the Windows partition size ( there were 24Gb used, I've changed virtual partition size from 100Gb to 40Gb) and killed the 150Mb partition where Windows stores system recovery data. I've installed Ubuntu on second virtual partition.

So now when the GRUB starts it cannot see the Windows installer. I think it's all OK with windows loader, just GRUB does not know about it.

So I need to specify it manually. Where and how?

Answer (score 15):

Run this from Ubuntu:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And reboot.

Windows should be in the Grub menu now.

Comment: Really?  If update-grub didn't find Windows when you first installed Ubuntu (or any linux distro) it's unlikely to do it now.

Comment: Running this command to find windows after first installing Ubuntu worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me as well.  I really appreciate how easy this method is.

Answer (score 1):

**edit Grub menu**

```
gksudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst


# This entry automatically added by the Debian installer for a non-linux OS
# on /dev/sdb1
title Windows 7
root (hd1,0)
savedefault
makeactive
map (hd0) (hd1)
map (hd1) (hd0)
chainloader +1
```

edit `/etc/fstab` so windows partitions are accesible in linux:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config

sudo ntfs-config
```

add mount points in `/media` for windows partitions

i think this will help you

Comment: unfortunately no file  /boot/grub/menu.lst

Comment: These instructions do not work with GRUB 2