# Dual boot not working with windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I used windows 7 ultimate.Then I tried Ubuntu 14.04 as dual boot. Watched a video on youtube installation process goes well I guess but when I rebooted it doesn't show me any option to boot with windows.

Now whenever I boot into my computer it is always in Ubuntu.
I am an absolute beginner any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem and most of the solutions involve reinstalling windows 7 and using windows bootloader, however I was told that when dual booting it is better to use grub. So I'd rather just get grub working.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that worked for me was from: [How to add Windows 7 loader to GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77439/how-to-add-windows-7-loader-to-grub)

In short I had to open terminal and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Which then created a grub config file. After reboot I saw an option to load my Windows 7 or Ubuntu.