# Ubuntu screwed up my computer

Tags: system-installation

I tried installing Ubuntu with Windows, and when I restarted my computer there was no Windows. And so I decided to reinstall windows and such, it won't let me. I want to go back to windows badly.....

Comment: You mean you want to uninstall ubuntu?@Josh

Comment: Did you decide to use the whole disk to install Ubuntu? Or to replace Windows? Did you instal Ubuntu in unallocated space? Do have a Windows installation medium (DVD/CD/USB/whatever you use to install)? Btw: installing another operating system has nothing to do with Ubuntu. How to install Windows is off topic and should be asked on http://superuser.com/ In case you did install Ubuntu on a separate partition and it is a matter of GRUB configuration: please provide an image of your disk layout from gParted.

Comment: No. I wanted to install Ubuntu with windows. I did it before on my older computer and It worked, just not on my newer one.

Answer (score 2):

sorry to hear about the issue

With all the Dual boot installations I have done, the Installer/Setup process always detects the alternately installed OS with no issue/problem.

I have on a usual setup 1xWindows, 1xDebian (or other Linux), 1x Ubunutu

Why aren't you able to reinstall Windows - any specific Error?

Also consider adding your Windows into Grub manually if you didn't break the Partition structure.

[How to add Windows 7 to Grub ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77439/how-to-add-windows-7-loader-to-grub)

Comment: When I tried to reinstall windows It came up with an error saying "this drive is locked"..